# Ettiquite for self-deleting an inadequately researched question

Tags: discussion

I have recently [asked](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158571/why-is-electric-current-labelled-i) what was in hindsight a woefully inadequately researched question.

That badly that had I actually looked at the most obvious place, I could have found the answer quite easily.  Instead, I was looking to find it in the less obvious places, like the history of modern electric circuits.

Clearly, the question is unsalvageable and there is nothing that can be done to improve it.

So, what should happen to it?  Should it remain on SE EE as an example of a bad question, or would it best be purged and its existence denied?

(Similar circumstance, but not quite the same thing being discussed [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/question-closed-with-insufficient-preliminary-research-cause))

Comment: Hint: there is a badge "Disciplined" for deleting one's own post that got score -3 or less.

Comment: @Nick,. isn't that for [+3 or higher](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/disciplined)?

Comment: You're right.  [Peer Pressure](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/peer-pressure) is for -3.

Comment: I have taken the hint and the question is now deleted. Clearly, with a [badge](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/peer-pressure) on offer, the etiquette to to delete.  It isn't one I aspired to!

Comment: Regardless of getting the badge or not, you've done the Right Thing both by deleting the question and by asking about it here in meta. Well done! +1

Comment: I have not seen the question myself as you had deleted it before I got there, but if it's not obvious to others how to get the question answered as it wasn't for you, another way out would have been to answer your own question, posting what you've found and explaining why it wasn't easy to find the answer. But if it was obvious (like googling) then best is to let the question rest in peace.